# flash actionscript rtmp load black screen issue display status

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I am using flash to publish webcam stream using H264 , but some times viewer side flash shows black screen even though stream connects to FMS is there a way to know if stream has started capture frame if not black then continue else reconnect . A way to find its black screen or not .

Comment: As stated below, you should listen for NetStatusEvent's that are dispatched by the NetStream and NetConnection. There are also a lot of useful [statistics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#info) you can get from a NetStream that you can use to infer that a client has stopped sending/receiving video.

Answer (score 0):

you should use events from NetConnection and NetStream to see if connections is persistent

but! if you have black screen, usualy it happens because of device, if device is streaming without problem and connection is lost on viewer's side then you should see latest frame. And, you are using stage 3d video ? if yes, then you should know, sometimes there are troubles with it.

Comment: I am using h264 and speex for audio it and published from flash player to FMS server some time black screen most times normal .

Comment: try to use other webcam